# Rails, is there a way to give a file_field an image by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an edit form for my articles.

Every article has an image.

I have Current Image and Change Image sections.

Here is my code:

```
<%=form_for @article, url: articles_update_path,remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|%>

<fieldset class="content-group">
  <legend class="text-bold">Images</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 text-semibold">Current image:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= image_tag @article.image_url(:thumb) unless @article.image.blank?%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 text-semibold">Change image:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.file_field :image, :class => 'file-input-custom', 'data-show-caption' => true, 'data-show-upload' => false, :accept => 'image/*'%>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<% end %>
```

Now the thing is that if the user chooses to edit the article and does not give an image again, there is no image.

I want to make my edit form so that if someone does not pick an image, the image that the article already has is saved.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using `gem 'carrierwave'` for image upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I found out that what I am asking is probably not possible.
You either have to use JavaScript, or you must check on your controller if the image passed is nil.

In my case I had to check in my **article_params** if the **params[:article][:image]** is nil or not.

```
def article_params
    if params[:article][:image]==""
        params.require(:article).permit(:id)
    else
        params.require(:article).permit(:id, :image)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if you are using `gem 'carrierwave'` for image upload .......

You can do this easily by overriding the `default_url` method in your `uploader`:

```
  def default_url
    # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
    # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
    'default.jpg'
  end
```

and Put your default.jpg file in app/assets/images folder.

Your image_tag will look like this .......

```
<%= image_tag @article.image.url(:thumb) || @article.default_url %>
```